# javascript code is not working latest chrome in android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, infinite-scroll

`element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight`

This is not working in latest chrome version in android ,I tested in firefox ,safari(both mobile devices and pc) and even pc chrome is working,i could not figure out why is it not working in android chome.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight

Comment: Not working how? Is it throwing an error or giving the wrong answer? If the answer is wrong, how is it wrong, for example is one of the sides too big or too small?

Comment: @Ryan1729,I am sorry it was my fault , i was using react refs wrongly.

Comment: No worries. The way we get better is not by avoiding being wrong, but by getting better at going from being wrong to being right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I struggled with this issue for a while and just figured out by debugging my phone connected to my computer. On desktop and iOS browsers everything works as expected but on Android Chrome exclusively element.scollTop is calculated in insane fractions. i.e `42.81747128182`.

Because of this on Android `element.scrollHeight - element.scrollTop === element.clientHeight` will not work.

Simply rounding off that decimal does this trick. Try:

`element.scrollHeight - Math.floor(element.scrollTop) === element.clientHeight`